# Check whether SharePoint Online URL is valid document library or not

Tags: sharepoint, graph, office365api, sharepoint-online, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a software where users of office 365 tenancy will copy / paste any url to the software and I need verify / correct that URL to a proper document library.

For example;

https://contoso.sharepoint.com/Projects/Current/Forms/AllItems.aspx

should automatically be corrected to

https://contoso.sharepoint.com/Projects/Current/

And if user types;

https://contoso.sharepoint.com/Lists/Task (Task list and NOT the library)

I should throw error saying its NOT a valid document library.

There are really lots of combination of URL to it. I can use Graph API / REST API (But NOT c# as its in PHP). I am really not able to fetch any API which can do this for me.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [sharepoint rest api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx) :

```
https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/team/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Lists/Example')/Properties
```

[image]

You could find the [vti_x005f_listservertemplate](http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2013/08/sharepoint-server-template-id-list.html)  property . it's a generic list if the value is 100 . and if value is 101, it's a Document Library .